# Sort object properties by child-object property value

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting, object

I have a solution but I'm not quite happy about the implementation.

Would like to get some feedback here on how this could be improved, either the sorting or maybe the data structure.

What I want to do is to make a sort order for the properties of an object by one of its sub-objects property value.

My data structure is the following:

object called champions:

```
{ '32': { played: 1, image: 'Amumu.png', won: 0 },
  '60': { played: 5, image: 'Elise.png', won: 3 },
  '79': { played: 4, image: 'Gragas.png', won: 3 },
  '245': { played: 1, image: 'Ekko.png', won: 0 },
  '254': { played: 2, image: 'Vi.png', won: 1 },
  '421': { played: 2, image: 'RekSai.png', won: 0 },
  // order is an array where I pushed all the objects image values
  order: 
   [ 'Amumu.png',
     'Elise.png',
     'RekSai.png',
     'Ekko.png',
     'Gragas.png',
     'Vi.png' ]
}
```

Now I want to create a sort order which sorts the object alphabetically by the image name.

This is how I'm doing it at the moment:

```
champions.order.sort(); // sorts the order array alphabetically
// loops to replace the strings of the order array with the
// corresponding parent object keys
for(var j =0; j < champions.order.length; j++){
    for(var k in champions){
        if(k != "order"){
            if(champions.order[j] === champions[k].image){
                champions.order[j] = k;
            }
        }
     }
};
```

Which gives me the desired result for the objects order property:

```
{ '32': { played: 1, image: 'Amumu.png', won: 0 },
  '60': { played: 5, image: 'Elise.png', won: 3 },
  '79': { played: 4, image: 'Gragas.png', won: 3 },
  '245': { played: 1, image: 'Ekko.png', won: 0 },
  '254': { played: 2, image: 'Vi.png', won: 1 },
  '421': { played: 2, image: 'RekSai.png', won: 0 },
  order: [ '32', '245', '60', '79', '421', '254' ] }
```

Any ideas if this can be achieved easier? Or with another data structure?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Object.keys()`

```
  var res = Object.keys(champions).slice(0, -1).sort(function(a, b) {
      return champions[a].image.toLowerCase() > champions[b].image.toLowerCase() ? 1 : 0
  })
```

Comment: Is this going to take into account the order given in the `order` property, which seems to be what the OP wants?